# How to clean Panel Data Efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, panel

I am transforming panel data. My original data is df and I want to transform it into df2. Price_1 means price in Jan. Price_2 means price in Feb and so on. And here is my solution, and my result is in df3.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
               'month': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
               'variable_name': ['price', 'price', 'price', 'quantity', 'quantity', 'quantity', 'price', 'price', 'price', 'quantity', 'quantity', 'quantity', 'price', 'price', 'price', 'quantity', 'quantity', 'quantity'],
               'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 ,18]
               })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               'price_1': [1, 7, 13],
               'price_2': [2, 8, 14],
               'price_3': [3, 9, 15],
               'quantity_1': [4, 10, 16],
               'quantity_2': [5, 11, 17],
               'quantity_3': [6, 12, 18]
               })
```

My solutions are:

```
month1 = df['month'].unique()
#date1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(date1)
#month1 = date1.month
var_name = df['variable_name'].unique()
var_name2=[]

for j in var_name:
    for i in month1:
        t = j + '_' + str(i)
        var_name2.append(t)

x = df.value
index_name = df['item'].unique()
m = index_name.shape[0]
n = len(var_name2) 
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x.values.reshape(m, n), index = index_name, columns = var_name2)
```

My question: The data will be much more in the future (about 2GB). So I was wondering how to transform the data efficiently in the python? (my solution seems perform poor). It is not necessary to be very efficient and function in the prevailed library is preferred. Thank you.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores_style`. Please explain how the program work/what it does, so that other people aren't forced to reverse engineer it. It might also be worth sharing some more context for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index(['item', 
              df.variable_name + '_' + df.month.apply(str)]
)['value'].unstack().reset_index()
```

the column names you want is the concatenation of `variable_name` and `month`.

so, to achieve that, set `item` & the concatenation expression as the index, `unstack` to pivot and finally `reset_index`

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. The firewall blocks me. Thank you for your answer. But I tried to calculate the excution time using your solution. It seems your solution takes longer time. Have you compared the excution time?